# How to plot a cluster in python prepared using categorical data

Tags: python, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, categorical-data

I have a high-dimensional dataset which is categorical in nature and I have used Kmodes to identify clusters, I want to visualize the clusters, what would be the best way to do that? PCA doesn't seem to be a recommended method for dimensionality reduction in a categorical dataset, how to visualize in such a scenario?

Comment: Maybe the Multiple Correspondence Analysis (MCA) package for python can help you with that. Check also that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41827660/reveal-k-modes-cluster-features

Comment: What do you *expect* to see on such data? There is no "scatter" to visualize, so a scatter plot doesn't seem to be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Agreeing with @DIMKOIM, Multiple Correspondence Analysis is your best bet. PCA is mainly used for continuous variables. To visualize your data, you can build a scatter plot from scratch.